# Trouble getting a moving script to read filename and perform actions based on this

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I am trying to get a mover batch script to read the filenames in a folder and do things to them based on the filename before moving them.

I have no trouble getting the files to be moved but I can't get the doing stuff based on filename part right.

```
@ECHO on
setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
SET src_folder=c:\recordz
SET tar_folder=\\TOWER\Temprec
:LOOP

  for /f "delims=" %%a IN ('dir "%src_folder%"\*.mpg /b') do (

    set "var=%%~na"
    Echo %var%
    Rem this part is supposed to check if NFL is part of the filename
If NOT "%var%"=="%var:NFL=%" (
            echo Found inside
        REN "%src_folder%\%%~na.mpg" "%%~na.ts"
    move %src_folder%\"%%~na.ts" %tar_folder%
) else (
        echo No cigar
        move %src_folder%\"%%~na.mpg" %tar_folder%
    )


)
REM Crafty 5 minute delay...
PING 1.1.1.1 -n 1 -w 1800000 >NUL
GOTO LOOP
```

When I run the above, I get this:

```
C:\Scripts>(
set "var=Feux_20161003_21002200"
Echo
If NOT "" == "NFL=" (
echo Found inside
 REN "c:\recordz\Feux_20161003_21002200.mpg" "Feux_20161003_21002200.ts"
 move c:\recordz\"Feux_20161003_21002200.ts" \\TOWER\Temprec
)  else (
echo No cigar
move c:\recordz\"Feux_20161003_21002200.mpg" \\TOWER\Temprec
)
)
ECHO is on.
Found inside
```

Comment: You need to  [enabledelayedexpansion](http://ss64.com/nt/delayedexpansion.html) - Delayed Expansion will cause variables to be expanded at execution time rather than at parse time.

Comment: I tried both with and without the delayed expansion but it still did not fix the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although you have enabled the delayed expansion you are not using it. Change % to ! inside the loop.

```
for /f "delims=" %%a IN ('dir "%src_folder%"\*.mpg /b') do (
    set var=%%~na
    Echo !var!
    Rem this part is supposed to check if NFL is part of the filename
    If NOT "!var!"=="!var:NFL=!" (
        echo Found inside
        REN "%src_folder%\%%~na.mpg" "%%~na.ts"
        move %src_folder%\"%%~na.ts" %tar_folder%
    ) else (
        echo No cigar
        move %src_folder%\"%%~na.mpg" %tar_folder%
    )
)
```

Comment: Thank you, will update if this solves my problem. Meanwhile, could you point me towards a resource that explains the difference between % and !

Comment: Thank you, this works perfectly. I would not have found this out on my own as I had no idea that exclamation points were a thing. At least it was not in the tutorial that I read.